# Join various tables with identical fields, but with changing prefix in the table names

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have various tables in Access all with the identical fields and I would like to merge them in one. The only issue is that they when I import them they all have different names - the only common thing they have is *USR02*. I have created an empty table with desired columns called USR_02_ALL. However, I cannot populate it with data from this table. I am using Access 2016. The code I got so far (from someone) is:

```
Sub Buildquery()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim sqlFinal As String
Dim sql1 As String
On Error GoTo Buildquery_Error

sql1 = "SELECT * INTO USR_02_ALL FROM ( " & vbCrLf
Dim sql2 As String
sql2 = "SELECT * FROM "
Dim sql3 As String
sql3 = "UNION ALL "

Set db = CurrentDb 
sqlFinal = sql1

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name Like "*" & "USR02" & "*" Then
        sqlFinal = sqlFinal & tdf.Name & " " & sql3 & sql2 & tdf.Name & vbCrLf
    End If
Next tdf

Debug.Print sqlFinal 'You can put this wherever you want
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub

Buildquery_Error:   
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Buildquery of Module AWF_Related"

End Sub
```

Comment: You dont call the SQL.  Also you can use the MSysObjects table to give you the table names using SQL rather than loop, then you can do some sort of union from that.

Comment: `vbCrLF` might introduce errors into the SQL - it should just be one long text string.  Does the final text in `sqlFInal` execute when pasted into the database as a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your final SQL at the moment:

```
SELECT * INTO USR_02_ALL FROM ( 
A_USR02_A UNION ALL SELECT * FROM A_USR02_A
B_USR02_B UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B_USR02_B
C_USR02_C UNION ALL SELECT * FROM C_USR02_C
```

It should look like this if you're inserting to a new table:

```
SELECT * INTO USR_02_ALL FROM
(
SELECT * FROM A_USR02_A
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B_USR02_B
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM C_USR02_C
)
```

or like this if you're appending to an existing table:

```
INSERT INTO USR_02_ALL 
SELECT      * 
FROM        (
            SELECT * FROM A_USR02_A 
            UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B_USR02_B 
            UNION ALL SELECT * FROM C_USR02_C
            )
```

This code will build that SQL (uncomment the *SQLFinal* line depending on what type of query you want to use):

```
Public Sub BuildQuery()

    Dim SQLFinal As String
    Dim SQL1 As String
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

    'Create a new table SQL
    'SQLFinal = "SELECT * INTO USR_02_ALL FROM (SELECT * FROM "

    'Append to existing table
    SQLFinal = "INSERT INTO USR_02_ALL SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM "

    SQL1 = " UNION ALL SELECT * FROM "

    For Each tdf In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If tdf.Name Like "*USR02*" Then
            SQLFinal = SQLFinal & tdf.Name & SQL1
        End If
    Next tdf

    SQLFinal = Left(SQLFinal, Len(SQLFinal) - Len(SQL1)) & ")"

    CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", SQLFinal).Execute

End Sub
```

Note it adds `" UNION ALL SELECT * FROM "` at the end of each statement ready for the next table name - it then removes the last instance of that text string.

Comment: Thank you! Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The command `SELECT * INTO USR_02_ALL FROM...` will create a new table that has the same fields as the result of the query. As you wrote "I have created an empty table...", this statement will fail with runtime error 3010 (*table already exists*).

If you want to insert data into an existing table, you can use the command `INSERT into USR_02_ALL select * FROM...`. Except if you want to get rid of duplicates, there is no point in combining all your tables into one statement. Instead, I would loop over the tables and issue a separate `INSERT`-Statement for each of them. For more details, see for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/insert-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Btw: As Nathan wrote in his comment: you don't issue the SQL-command. You need to add a statement like `db.Execute sqlFinal`.